# xtables_find_match in g++ does not work but it is fine in gcc

Tags: c++, iptables

Iptables is a c-implemented lib.

My project is based on C++, so I create a new header file h1.h, which will be included in my c++ file through 'extern "c"{#include h1.h}'.

Many iptables-lib functions work fine in my c++ project, except xtables_find_match() in do_command().

==============================

```
gcc -c -std=c99 -o file1.o file1.c
g++ -c -std=c++0x -o file2.o file2.cpp
g++ -o myapp file1.o file2.o
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Is there a compiler/linker error? Does the program crash? How do you call the function?

Comment: That should be `extern "C"` with a capital `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like xtables_init_all and init_extensions should be called first.
otherwise load_extension will exit silently.

xtables_find_match will call load_extension.